# Reexport all typings inside a typescript .d.ts definition file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there any way to reuse typings from one `.d.ts` file inside another `.d.ts file` to declare a module?

For example lets say we have the following vendor file:

*node_modules/some-fancy-module/types.d.ts*

```
  export const valueA: number;
  export const valueB: number;
```

Now in my project file I would like to declare that all `*.special-file` imports will return `valueA` and `valueB` as shown on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html.

*typings.d.ts*

```
declare module '*.special-file' {
  export * from 'some-fancy-module/types.d.ts';
}
```

unfortunately I can't manage to use those typings:

```
import {valueA} from './my.special-file';
```

*Error*: `Module '"*.special-file"' has no exported member 'valueA'`

Screenshot:

[image: codesandbox screenshot of the issue]

CodeSandbox as seen on the screenshot:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reexport-types-5h8hb?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Actually your code works pretty fine, could you share your tsconfig?

Comment: I added a codesandbox with a tsconfig and the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can import and then export within the declaration. The following works:

```
declare module '*.foo' {
  import {valueA} from './third-party/types.d.ts';
  export = valueA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Wildcard module declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations) is clearly specified that after declaring a module with wildcard you also need to import it, but in the code you posted you don't.

You could try to import the module(s) as well after the wildcard module declaration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - my last code snippet shows the import statement.

Comment: Sorry @jantimon , if `import {valueA} from './my.special-file';` is in the same file as `declare module '*.special-file' {` it means I didn't understood and I'll simply remove this useless answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is your sandbox fork # 1: https://codesandbox.io/s/reexport-types-ovrtt?file=/tsconfig.json

It also works with external libraries https://github.com/Drag13/reexport/blob/master/src/index.ts

If you don't want to go with wildcard `import test from "*.special-file"`, you still can use named import:

`import test from "test.special-file";`

However, it has one big issue. Code compiles perfectly but it is not working. Compiled index.js looks like:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var test_special_file_1 = require("test.special-file");
console.log(test_special_file_1.hello() + " " + test_special_file_1.test());
```

And, of course, test.special-file not exists.

Comment: But I don't want to import all files in that directory - so I can't use the asterisk like you did here: `import test from "*.special-file"`

Comment: Ok, change it to the ```import test from "test.special-file";```. It also works, @jantimon

Comment: Cool - could you explain how it works?

Can I also reexport it e.g. to also use it for `.special-file2` without changing the third party code?

Comment: It's just combination of declaration and wildcard. Works the same way as ```declare module "*.json"``` actually. But I don't get the second question, what exactly you want to reexport?

Comment: I can't change the third party code to `declare module` that's why I want to use the typings inside my own typings file like shown in the screenshot

Comment: In this case this approach with reexport should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly your `some-fancy-module` package, but when I try with "my" package it still working fine.

And your codesandbox is not correctly , because a relative module is not acceptable in an ambient module.

This is my example: I am using `n8n-nodes-chatwork` as `some-fancy-module`

typings.d.ts

```
declare module '*.foo' {
  export * from 'n8n-nodes-chatwork/dist/credentials/Chatwork.credentials.d'; // removed ".ts"
}
```

index.ts, `Chatwork` as your `valueA`

```
import {Chatwork} from './demo.foo';

type x = typeof Chatwork;
```

or

```
import test from './demo.foo';

type x = typeof test.Chatwork;
```

This is my sanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reexport-types-05ftm?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

Update: Typescript 5.0 will have a feature to solve this question:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/52217